# Is there a possibility to declare a member variable that takes up no memory?

Tags: c++, class, templates, member

Given a template class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
T member;
//... some other members that are not of interest here
};
```

Is there any type I can give as T to prevent `member` from taking up unnecessary memory?
At first `void` popped to my mind but I know that you cannot declare variables of `void`.

*NOTE*
Of course the example is simplified. The background is a class that holds some information but can get additional information added by the user. When the user does not want to add additional information it should be possible to leave them out. So basically if the user wants to store additional data he will construct `C<MyAdditionalData>` but if he does not it should be like `C<NoData>` and there will be no data. Of course i could write some kind of template specialization but I don't like writing everything twice.

**EDIT**
Ok I found that an empty class is the closest I can get (still consumes 1 byte or even 4/8 because of alignment) so far, so my question now is: 
Is there already some standard empty class that I should be using for this to make my code more readable?

Comment: You don't have to have a member, if you don't want to. `class C { };`

Comment: @BoPersson: Of course but I do want the template to have the possibility to store a member.

Comment: maybe you should tell us what your goal is instead of how you are trying to achieve it. It's hard to five advice without knowing what you are trying to achieve (afterall you can't keep `member` from taking up memory, if you need it...)

Comment: @Grizzly: Added some explanation to my example.

Comment: @Nobody class Foo{}; = empty class. However do note that even this class takes up 1 byte in memory.

Comment: @FailedDev: Yes already had that in my edit, with another question regarding it.

Comment: Maybe EBCO (Empty base class optimization) is what you need. When I read "C++ templates. The complete guide" of David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis I've encountered it. The book was in russian, so I couldn't give you a pagenum, but you could find this term inside the subject index in the end of the book. It's interesting to discuss this thing, because I rarely encounter a need for such a tricky thing in my practice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a data member no, because objects are never size zero, and there's no get-out clause for data members.

However, a base class subobject can have size zero if it's empty. Hence:

```
template <typename T>
struct Member {
    T member;
};

template <>
struct Member<void> {
};

template <typename T>
class C : private Member<T>
{
//... some other members that are not of interest here
};
```

should work, I think. But you might trip over the fact that `C<void>::member` doesn't exist, so any member functions that use it won't compile for `C<void>`, including constructors.

> if the user wants to store additional data he will construct
>   `C<MyAdditionalData>`

Why not have `C` a non-template class with no additional data member, and if the user wants to add data members, use `C` as a base class? Remember to give `C` a protected destructor -- every base class should have either a protected destructor or a virtual destructor, but since your `C` template class doesn't have a virtual destructor then there's no need for the non-template version to be virtual either.

Along these lines, you could do:

```
class CNoData
{
//... some other members that are not of interest here
};

template <typename T>
class CWithData<T> : CNoData
{
T member
// have to duplicate constructors, unfortunately.
};
```

and if you really need it, add a type trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
     typedef CWithData<T> type;
};

template <>
struct C<void> {
    typedef CNoData type;
};
```

Then where you would have written `C<MyAdditionalData>`, now you write `CWithData<MyAdditionalData>`, and where you would have written `C<some_type_that_might_be_void>` you write `typename C<some_type_that_might_be_void>::type`.

Comment: +1 I think this pretty much solves the problem. At first I was afraid of additional runtime overhead but then I realized that there are no virtual functions, so everything should be resolved neatly at compile time. Having to duplicate the constuctors is a small minus but fortunately they are the small part of the class. In retrospective I wonder why this did not come to my mind, because it is much cleaner, even in the logic of implementing this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Specialize your template class for a type `NoData` and don't define the member in this specialization.

```
template <class T>
class C {
   T member;
...
};

template<>
class C<NoData> {
   // Do not declare that member
};
```

Comment: Thats one of the things I thought of, but how do I avoid defining each of the functions again in the specialization? I did not include them in the example but there are around 10 functions and they are quite long.

Comment: Macros or inheritance. If you use inheritance, you can have the template inheriting plain base class, so the base class will be the parameterless solution by itself.

Comment: @Nobody I'd go with inheritance. And don't forget that inheritance in both directions is allowed, and they provide different possibilities.

Comment: Yes I choose inheritance over macros, because it is much cleaner. What two direction do you mean when talking about *both directions*?

Comment: @Nobody your template class (all of its specializations) can inherit from a common base class, this is the upward direction. Or, you could define a template derived class that inherits from your template class (and all of its specializations), so this is the downward direction. You get slightly different functionalities out of doing it either way (or possibly both ways together)

Answer (score 3):

> Ok I found that an empty class is the closest I can get so far, so my question now is: Is there already some **standard empty class** that I should be using for this to make my code more readable?

No. You can define one yourself:

```
struct standard_empty_class {};
```

Use it.

> So basically if the user wants to store additional data he will construct `C<MyAdditionalData>` but if he does not it should be like `C<NoData>` and there will be no data.

I don't understand this. If the user doesn't want to store any data, then why even then you need a class, and still need to write `C<NoData>`? Just forget that case. No data means no class. Does it not solve that?

Comment: Ok thank you for the information. I was afraid that there is none, so now I have to think of a place where to put this, so it is visible to every user (preventing hundreds of new empty classes from emerging :)

Comment: @Nobody: Define this class in your utility header. :-)

Comment: Regarding your second comment: The basic class stores a graph topology. The data that would be added by the user are additional information to the nodes/edges that are not necessary for the graph itself. If the user only wants to store the graph with no additional information on nodes/edges, then it would be nice to waste no memory on useless members (the additional data).

Comment: @Nobody: The Standard defines two different classes for such functionality.

Comment: @Nobody: In that case, you probably need a vector of some generic type (if the data to be stored can be anything, not known in advance). Have you considered using `std::vector<boost::any> data`. Well, basically I'm not sure what you need.

Comment: @DeadMG: Would you be so kind as to name them?^^ Nawaz: The data being stored is known at compile-time (with user I meant programmers using these template classes). Naturally I want to have the same data on each node/edge of the graph so my gut told me to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. Actually, it's the other way arround. Even an empty class occupies memory (one byte) when instantiated, so that the program can differ between instances. That is

```
class A {
};

A a, b;  // vars of type A
```

Then `a` and `b` must take some memory so your program can refer to them, for example, `if (a == b)`. You can't do it if they don't use memory.

Comment: Well the question was not so much about instances but how to give the compiler a hint to not even create that field. Unfortunately that does not seem possible, but I wanted to be sure, so that is why I asked

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, the template already contains some other data. It it has virtual methods, then that's one more member.

Adding an extra member is a very small overhead that can be simply ignored, so I'd just use C. (or even char if there are other members smaller than alignment)

Use typedef for better clarity:

```
typedef C<int> CEmptyGraphNode;
```

Comment: oh, actually enobayram's solution works wonders, but I'd still keep the typedef : )